# Can pydoc operate on a pyd, or is there an equivalent to pydoc that operates on a pyd

Tags: python, pydoc

It seems to me that pydoc only works on py source code files.

Can it be used on a compiled pyd file in some way? The error I get in attempting that is

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

which arises, obviously, due to the fact that the compiled pyd contains NUL bytes.

Comment: What would you expect the documentation drawn from a compiled file to be?

Comment: `__doc__` can be pulled from reflection for example. And that can be embedded in pyd files.

Comment: You can also use help on a pyd. Is what I'm asking that odd?

Comment: You could use a decompiler & run pydoc on what it produces.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work. The pyd is written in C++.

Comment: Why can't you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) library, specially its [source code (3.9)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pydoc.py), the function [`importfile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b6f4e5e13ebd1f957b47f7415b53d0869bdbac6/Lib/pydoc.py#L300) works with *.py* and *.pyc*, but does not with *.pyo* nor *.pyd* files.

It may be possible to write custom code to parse the content of a [*.pyd* file](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll) and re-use parts of `pydoc` to generate the documentation, but I think it is not simple.

Another way is through the builtin [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) that calls `pydoc`. here is a proof of concept :

```py
# file: main.py
"""
Hello pydoc !
"""
```

```py
# file: setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("main",  ["main.py"]),
]

setup(
    name='My pyd file',
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

(I have installed Cython in my venv, so that I can compile *.py* files into *.pyd*)

I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` which produces the `main.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` file.
I move this file into another directory (to not mess the import later), and I use this file :

```py
# file: get_pydoc.py
import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    help(main)
```

which is in the same directory than the *.pyd* file (and nothing else). When ran, it prints :

```
Help on module main:

NAME
    main - Hello pydoc !

DATA
    __test__ = {}

FILE
    c:\\pycharmprojects\stack_overflow\q68002833_check\main.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
```

which proves it is possible.

Looking at the [CPython implementation for `help` as of 3.9](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L88) we can see it only does `return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)`. So we can call `pydoc` directly :

```py
# file: get_pydoc.py
import pydoc

import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pydoc.help(main)
```

and still have the same output.

But it prints its output directly on stdout, which is not convenient. Looking at its [Cpython 3.9 implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pydoc.py#L2042) that it uses by default its `output` field, which is a property ([see here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pydoc.py#L1988)) that returns `sys.stdout` if no `output` has been provided to the constructor, which is the case for the [default `Helper`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pydoc.py#L2207).

So by constructing a new `Helper` object whose output is an in-memory [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO), we have the following code :

```
# file: get_pydoc.py
import io
import pydoc

import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doc_content = io.StringIO()
    helper = pydoc.Helper(output=doc_content)
    helper.help(main)
    print(doc_content.getvalue())
```

I think it answers your question : you can write a script that will get the pydoc from a *.pyd* file. It is just not as straightforward, because it is very less common.